# HTTP redirect works but HTTPS does not

Tags: http, redirect, https, dns

My website envistiamall.com uses *Zendesk* for my support site. I have a DNS 301 (Moved Permanently) redirect to redirect support.envistiamall.com to https://envistiamall.zendesk.com/. This works fine if you enter http://support.envistiamall.com, or just support.envistiamall.com. But if you enter https://support.envistiamall.com, it refuses to connect.

The A record of the domain actually points to a *Shopify store*, so I don't have immediate access to an HTACCESS entry to fix it, if that is the best way.

I do have a hosting account, so I could point `support.envistiamall.com` to my hosting account and then redirect to *Zendesk* from there if necessary. But I'm in over my head and I am not sure what the problem actually is, so I am not sure how to go about fixing it.

Comment: What's the response code when it is refusing to connect? Can you check chrome console and network tab to get more information?

Comment: I got nothing on both the Console and the Network tab. It's the standard Chrome Can't Connect Screen. It says:

This site can’t be reached
support.envistiamall.com refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Looks like your server is not listening on 433 port.